# SharePoint Migration from 2013 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, visual-studio-2012, migration

Please, can someone help. I need to migrate custom visual studio .wsp solutions from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online, how do I go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately these will have to be rewritten as they are not supported in SharePoint Online.

Depending on the solution you can rewrite these as SharePoint Add-Ins or as client side solutions using SharePoint Framework.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/transform-farm-solutions-to-the-sharepoint-app-model

Answer (score 1):

There are are two types of solutions (wsp) in SharePoint on-premise:

- Sandbox and
- Farm solution

We used to deploy the sandbox solution to SharePoint online till the year 2016 now does not support, but we cannot deploy the **farm solution**

So, if you have a farm solution, you need re-develop the functionality or solution using the modern SharePoint technology - like SPFx framework.

Comment: Sandboxed solutions have been deprecated since 2014, not sure how long it will be possible to upload and use them (actually suprised if it still works!) [Info here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Sandboxed solutions with code have been deprecated since 2014. Sandboxed solutions without code still be supported. But anyway, developers must use SharePoint Framework asset deployment instead. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package